# Python - whoops - installed Python2.6 when I have 2.7 - default is now 2.6 - want 2.7 back

Tags: python, linux

I am on ubuntu 11.10.  I installed python2.6 becuased I have to work in a virtualenv.

On the command line, when I start python, the default is python2.6.

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python

Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jul  4 2012, 09:17:51) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How do I change back to python2.7 for the default?

Comment: Try file /usr/local/bin/python please :). It should be a symlink. You can change the symlink back to python2.7, I just don't know the exact path on ubuntu. (it should be somewhere near python2.6!

Comment: I have a vague feeling that update-alternatives will be involved...  Not sure what effect switching the default Python is going to have on the packages on your computer that require 2.6 though... :)

Comment: Yup...that worked.   Just deleted the sym link and added sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

check python at this place:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

it should be your original python 2.7, or you can find python2.7 by:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep python
```