# Python virtualenviroments - how to select python version

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am running ubuntu 11.10 and my default python is 2.7.  I just installed python 2.6.8 and when I create a virtualenviroment I would like the virtualenviroment to use python 2.6.

How do I do that?

```
 mkvirtualenv myve --no-site-packages ?????
```

Comment: You should probably just incorporate this into your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321359/python-whoops-installed-python2-6-when-i-have-2-7-default-is-now-2-6-wan).

Comment: I used  mkvirtualenv myve --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python2.6

Comment: yes, the -p option is teh way to go.

Comment: you can also set a default python system-wide with `update-alternatives` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I would use is:

- to install Miniconda/Anaconda
- create a conda environment with the desired python version via

```
conda create -n my-env-name python=<python-version>
```

- use venv or virtualenv in the created then activated conda environment (if needed)